# How to prove $f(n) = O(g(n)), g(n) = O(f(n))$ or both?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

1. f(n) = n log n, g(n) = n sqrt(n)/2
2. f(n) = (n^2-n)/2 , g(n) = 6n

using big-O definition finding c, n0?

i have tried with big-O notation:
Let
f
f, the function to be estimated, be a real or complex valued function and let
g
g, the comparison function, be a real valued function. Let both functions be defined on some unbounded subset of the positive real numbers, and
g
(
x
)
g(x) be strictly positive for all large enough values of
x.

exist c,n0 so that f(x) <= c g(n) for all n >= n0, where c and n0 are positive constants(c is to find and is not unique).

For the first one for example:

just looking the functions, we see f(n) seems to be O(g(n)) because g(n) is polynomial.
So I've tried to work on f(n):
$$n log n \leq c  \frac{n \sqrt n} {2} $$

$$ 2log n \leq c   \sqrt n $$

$$ c \geq \frac{2 log n} {\sqrt n}$$
now my issue is find c and $n_0$

Comment: What have you tried? What is $c$?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: of course I have tried and I m stuck in a transcendental equation, I m not able to find solution for the constants.

Comment: $n_0$ can be replaced by $1$ in the definition, and you don't need to find explicitely some $c,$ you only need to (dis-)prove its existence, i.e. to (dis-)prove that the sequence $\left(\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right)$ is bounded. $\left(\frac{2\log n}{\sqrt n}\right)$ is bounded because it converges to $0.$ Its reciprocal is unbounded because it tends to $\infty.$